# Getting "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" in a Python program

Tags: python, python-turtle

```
import turtle      
wn = turtle.Screen()  
Kasey = turtle.Turtle()

sides = input("Number of sides in polygon?"  )
length = input("Length of the sides in polygon?" )
colorname = input("Color of polygon?" )
Hcolor = input("Fill color of polygon?")

Kasey.pencolor(colorname)
Kasey.fillcolor(Hcolor)

Kasey.begin_fill()
for i in range(int(sides)):
  Kasey.forward (int(length))
  Kasey.left (int(360)/int(sides))

Kasey.end_fill()
```

Error:

```
Number of sides in polygon? 3
Length of the sides in polygon?5
Color of polygon?red
Fill color of polygon?blue

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-108-82ed860f1049>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/kasey/turtle.py', wdir='/home/kasey')

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/kasey/turtle.py", line 18, in <module>
    Kasey.fillcolor(Hcolor)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: I fixed it is this better?

Comment: You seem to have named one of your file as `turtle.py` (`/home/kasey/turtle.py`). Name it to something else, so that it doesn't conflict with `import turtle`. Somewhere you defined `fillcolor` as a string, which replaces the actual [`fillcolor`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/turtle.html#turtle.fillcolor) method.

Comment: I changed the file name and i'm still getting the same error code for fill color is their a different call i could use?

Comment: @GinoMempin, even renaming the variable `Hcolor` to be `fillcolor` won't cause this error.  Going back into the history of the OP's post, I don't see an obvioius scenario that would short of `Kasey.fillcolor = "..."` before also calling `Kasey.fillcolor(Hcolor)` which seems inconsistent with the code provided.  Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Naming your source file `turtle.py` is a serious mistake, but it doesn't account for the error message you got as it should have failed earlier in the code.  I tried various failure scenarios but couldn't reproduce yours.

I would have structured your code as follows:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

sides = int(input("Number of sides in polygon: "))
length = int(input("Length of the sides in polygon: "))
pen_color = input("Color of polygon: ")
fill_color = input("Fill color of polygon: ")

screen = Screen()

kasey = Turtle()
kasey.color(pen_color, fill_color)

kasey.begin_fill()

for _ in range(sides):
    kasey.forward(length)
    kasey.left(360 / sides)

kasey.end_fill()

screen.mainloop()
```

See if that works any better in your Anaconda environment.  (The last line might cause problems in your environment -- remove it if needed.)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Kasey.fillcolor(Hcolor)` with `Kasey.color(<pen color>, <fill color>)`
Watch [this](https://youtu.be/lev0HW6Bb6c) link to find out more.